# How to retrieve unique rows by an index column in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have the following Google Spreadsheet:

```
id1 mkdmc   cdjnc
id2 cn39    cncn
id3 cndc    cncn
id1 3mc     cm
```

And I want to transform it into:

```
id1 mkdmc   cdjnc
id2 cn39    cncn
id3 cndc    cncn
```

So to remove the row that has a duplicated id1 in column A. Note that the row isn't fully duplicated, just the value in column A.

How would I go about doing this with a formula?

Answer (score 2):

This could be simplified by using curly brackets {} within the vlookup to indicate which columns we would like to return.
For example - 2 columns:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(unique(A:A), A:B, {1,2}, false)
```

3 columns:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(unique(A:A), A:C, {1,2,3}, false)
```

This can then be easily expanded for any number of columns and the user can choose which columns they need eg: {1,2,5,7,9,10}.

Answer (score 1):

```
={unique(A:A), arrayformula(vlookup(unique(A:A), A:B, 2, false))}
```

Explanation:

- A table of 2 columns is constructed in a single formula (expanding to 3 columns is left as an exercise to the reader)
- The first column is the list of unique IDs
- The second column looks up the 1st value by that id in the second column of source